# How to output only English labels in SPARQL query?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I don't understand why this SPARQL queries produce duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?WikidataItem ?itemLabel
WHERE {  
  ?WikidataItem rdfs:label ?itemLabel. 
  ?WikidataItem ?label "Mozilla Firefox"@en.  
}
LIMIT 5
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FWikidataItem%20%3FitemLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3FWikidataItem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel.%20%0A%20%20%3FWikidataItem%20%3Flabel%20%22Mozilla%20Firefox%22%40en.%20%20%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%205%0A).

Is it producing a row of output in every language? How can I change my query in order for it to produce only the single result in English?

### Update

I'm still confused about how to solve my problem, since I perhaps oversimplified my example. I actually am using `FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "firefox"@en))` among other things to limit my query. How do I output only the English language label for each entry?

Comment: Do you need just `FILTER(lang(?itemLabel)='en')`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it producing a row of output in every language?

Yes, you're correct: `?itemLabel` match labels in all languages.

Try simply `SELECT * {?item rdfs:label "Mozilla Firefox"@en}`.

If you want to project a variable, use `VALUES`:

```
SELECT * {VALUES (?label) {("Mozilla Firefox"@en)} ?item rdfs:label ?label}
```